# How do I join a custom game from spectator mode?

Tags: overwatch

I'm watching a custom game as a spectator and a spot opens up. When I look at the lobby, I can only invite other friends to fill the spot, but I can't fill it myself. Is there some combination that I am missing or is the solution to quit out and re-join as a non-spectator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, there is no way other than leaving and re-joining, without the custom game moderator (lobby owner) changing you from a spectator in the lobby, so ask in match chat to be moved by the game owner or PM the owner.